# Binding multiple Sources to a ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datatemplate

I have a ListView with a dataTemplate which I need to bind to 3 different sources with the same index. I think I have to do this completely in XAML, because the sources (`chart`) only exists in xaml. I'm using the MVVM Pattern."
I have wrote down how it "should" work, the index `i` is the common key.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ???}">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel>
             <!-- Small rectangle filled with the same color as the corresponding line -->
            <Rectangle 
              Height="10"
              Width="10" 
              Fill="{Binding ElementName=chart, Path=Series[i].LineStroke}" />
            <!-- The title of the corresponding line -->
            <TextBlock
              x:Name="Title"
              Text="{Binding ElementName=chart, Path=Series[i].DataSeries.Title}" />
            <!-- The actual value of the corresponding line on the current position-->
            <TextBlock
              x:Name="Value"
              Text="{Binding ElementName=chart, Path=Behaviour.Behaviours[0].CurrentPoints[i].Y}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You are using MVVM.. so shouldn't you create a **ViewModel** for this case? Class containing both Series and Behaviour. Then use this ViewModel as a binding source to ListView.

Comment: I have a ViewModel which provides only data for the chart control, but the chart creates the colors and only the chart knows which Y-Point is currently selected. And the chart is only known in the view, so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mh, lets see. How about you bind you listview to `chart.Series` this way you get the right number of elements. An then in your data template you bind the properties of the series. For the behaviour you could use `MultiBinding` and a converter to extract the data

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Series, ElementName=chart}">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
     <StackPanel>
         <!-- Small rectangle filled with the same color as the corresponding line -->
        <Rectangle 
          Height="10"
          Width="10" 
          Fill="{Binding Path=LineStroke}" />
        <!-- The title of the corresponding line -->
        <TextBlock
          x:Name="Title"
          Text="{Binding Path=DataSeries.Title}" />
        <!-- The actual value of the corresponding line on the current position-->
        <TextBlock x:Name="Value">
          <TextBlock.Text>
              <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ChartSeriesBehaviourConverter}">
                 <Binding ElementName=chart/>
                 <Binding/>
              <MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Now you should get the `chart` and the current series object passed into your converter where you should be able to do something like `var idx = chart.Series.IndexOf(s)` so you can access the corresponding point in the behaviours.